# Getting all values from N amount of tuples

Tags: python

I created a recursive function to show all k-sized subsets from a bigger set. There is no problem when simply printing out the subsets, but I am running into trouble when I want to return the sets, should there be a need to use them later on.

This is the output for a starting set [3,5,7,9]

```
((((0, 0), (0, [3, 5])), ((0, [3, 7]), ([3, 9], 0))), (((0, [5, 7]), ([5, 9], 0)), (([7, 9], 0), (0, 0))))
```

This was just a quick snippet to see how what the output looks like and it looks like this:

```
a=list1([3,5,7,9],0,0,0,[],2)


for i in a:
    for j in i:
        for k in j:
            print(k)
```

```
(0, 0)

(0, [3, 5])

(0, [3, 7])

([3, 9], 0)

(0, [5, 7])

([5, 9], 0)

([7, 9], 0)

(0, 0)
```

Since the indexes that the lists I want are on change from tuple to tuple and the depth to which you need to go also changes depending on how large the starting set was, I really can't figure out how to extract only the final lists from the output.

Comment: I think you need a have a recursive function that checks the types of each element before deciding whether to extract or go deeper. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

```
list_of_lists=list()
def test_tuple(t): #where t is a tuple
    for element in tuple:
        if type(element) == type(list()):
            list_of_lists.append(element)
        elif type(element) == type(tuple()):
            test_tuple(element)
```

Since you've already got your output stored in a large tuple, you just need to pass that large tuple to test_tuple and declare a variable that will contain all the extracted lists. Unless you do something like make an infinitely recursive list of lists then this should do the trick.